# Need a function or something to run all of my other functions

Tags: r

I currently have like 20 functions to score some tests that have different versions. Hopefully the following code will allow this to make sense:

```
#pmat
x <- function(){
pmatFv1 <- function(df){...}
pmatFv2 <- function(df){...}
pmatFv3 <- function(df){...}
}
```

How can i make this so that all i need to do is click once/run a function that will run all of my other functions? In this case I will need to  be able to call `pmatFv1`, `pmatFv2`, and `pmatFv3` separately, but I do not want to have to run all of them in order to have access. For example, i could have 30 pmat functions to run, i just want to run one function that runs them all so that i can call the 15th or 25th, etc. In the code example I tried with "x" but this did not seem to work.

Comment: Are all of those functions named `pmat*`?

Comment: No, the screenshot shows just pmat, but there are other functions with different names that would be included.. I just want one function that runs all of my functions if possible so that i can access them individually without having to run them all separately.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have several objects in the `.GlobalEnv`, not necessarily functions. And the functions are not necessarily named `pmat*`.

```
pmatFv1 <- function(df){invisible(df)}
pmatFv2 <- function(df){invisible(df)}
pmatFv3 <- function(df){invisible(df)}
pmatFv4 <- letters[1:5]
otherFun <- function(x){invisible(2*x)}
```

Now, first get all objects in a list with a combination `ls/mget`.

```
funAll <- mget(ls())
```

Then determine which ones are functions. Note that the list `funAll` is a *named list*.

```
ok <- sapply(funAll, inherits, "function")
ok
# otherFun  pmatFv1  pmatFv2  pmatFv3  pmatFv4 
#     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE

funAll[!ok] <- NULL
funAll
#$otherFun
#function(x){invisible(2*x)}
#
#$pmatFv1
#function(df){invisible(df)}
#
#$pmatFv2
#function(df){invisible(df)}
#
#$pmatFv3
#function(df){invisible(df)}
```

The functions in `funAll` can now be used one by one:

```
x <- funAll[[1]](1:5)
x
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Or all in one go, passing their arguments in the dots argument. (Optionally, use named argument `Which` to run only the 15th or 25th, etc.)

```
runAllFunctions <- function(fun_list, ..., Which = seq_along(fun_list)){
  y <- lapply(fun_list[Which], function(f) f(...))
  y
}

runAllFunctions(funAll, x)
```